# Spaces in email id in speech to text

Tags: android, voice-recognition, speech-to-text

When i give my email id as input to voice recognition in android there are spaces between words .

Eg. my mail id is navyasri972@gmail.com but voice recognition is converting to navya sri 972 @gmail.com .

I want to use speech to text in my app.So please could you give me a solution to avoid spaces between words in gmail id?

Is there any function to avoid spaces.Please help me guys.

I want to make a simple speech to text app.Help me guys.

I am following this tutorial

http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-speech-to-text-tutorial/

Comment: Are you using STT to 'only' write the email address, e.g. 'navya sri 972 @gmail.com' or is it part of a longer string, e.g. 'My email address is navya sri 972 @gmail.com'?

Answer (score 0):

use replace() like example below :

String str = "wael says hi";
str = str.replace(" ", "");

Comment: But this would replace all the spaces in a string. If you have a long string, how  would you recognize only the email address and replace 'those' spaces within the email address?

Comment: I don't know how you work exactly with the voice recognition.?
But you know that the email can't have any spaces, so whatever the result you should remove any space.
Only if you have another data in your recognition result other than your gmail.?

Comment: You can easily remove spaces if you have a string that you 'know' is an email address, for example, when you are using STT to fill in only one text field. However, it becomes more complicated if the email address is part of a longer sentence e.g. 'My email address is navya sri 972 @gmail.com' and you want to remove just the spaces in the email address. OP should clarify.